# need javascript best sorting best practice for ascending, descending

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a snippet for my examples, i need best practice of sorting algorithm with asc, desc convertion. this snippet have many complex for according to job, because string numbers always required in array. how can i simplify this snippet.

```
const data = [['aaa','22'], ['aba','23'],['baa','12'],['caa','122']]

console.log(data)
console.log('\n')

var columnIndex = 0;
var order = 'DESC';

data.sort((a, b) => {
  if (!Number.isInteger(Number.parseInt(a[columnIndex]))) {
      if (a[columnIndex] < b[columnIndex]) {
          return order === "ASC" ? -1 : 1;
      }
      if (a[columnIndex] > b[columnIndex]) {
          return order === "ASC" ? 1 : -1;
      }
      return 0;
  }
  else {
      return order === "ASC" ? (Number(a[columnIndex].match(/(\d+)/g)) - Number((b[columnIndex].match(/(\d+)/g)))) : ( Number((b[columnIndex].match(/(\d+)/g))) - Number(a[columnIndex].match(/(\d+)/g)));
  }
});
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use partial application with a curried function like `sortBy()` below to determine sort order and criteria without relying on global variables. I've even provided usage in an event listener that automatically updates the output whenever the inputs are changed:

```js
const data = [['aaa', 22], ['aba', 23], ['baa', 12], ['caa', 122]];
const sortBy = (o, i) => (a, b) => (-(a[i] < b[i]) || +(a[i] > b[i])) * o;

function update () {
  const [order, index] = Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('select'),
    input => Number(input.value)
  );
  const sort = sortBy(order, index);

  document.querySelector('#json').textContent = JSON.stringify(data.sort(sort));
}

document.body.addEventListener('input', update);

update();
```

```html
<select name="order" value="1">
  <option value="1">Ascending</option>
  <option value="-1">Descending</option>
</select>

<select name="index" value="0">
  <option value="0">String</option>
  <option value="1">Number</option>
</select>

<pre id="json"></pre>
```

This is a modification of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51398944/1541563) to [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value), which contains much more explanation about how `sortBy()` works.

Comment: but even for if i don't use string numbers

Comment: If you want a recommendation for best practice, don't store your numbers as strings. JSON format allows numeric values, so use them. Strings are sorted lexicographically, so `'122' < '22'` because `'1' < '2'`.